# Alternate approach for Case statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, case

I have a query insert statement like shown below

```
 insert into my_table
 select col1,col2,CASE
    WHEN EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A m WHERE m.COLA='XXX' AND m.id=b.id
      )
    THEN
      (SELECT m.COLB FROM Table_A m WHERE m.COLA='XXX' AND m.id=b.id
      )
    ELSE 'Not Open'
  END XXX, 
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A m WHERE m.COLA='YYY' AND m.id=b.id
      )
    THEN
      (SELECT m.COLB FROM Table_A m WHERE m.COLA='YYY' AND m.id=b.id
      )
    ELSE 'Not Open'
  END YYY, 
  .
  .
  .
  .
  . -- ~150 case statement
  from Test b,table_main c
  where b.id=c.id
```

Here we have case statement which is referring same table (TABLE_A) but checking for different values(XXX,YYY,etc..,) in each statement. This is taking so much time. We are trying to optimize this `insert` query. Could someone help here?

Comment: Can you please show sample table data?  Sounds like you need another join table maybe?

Comment: Can there be multiple records in Table_A for the condition m.id = b.id and m.COLA ='any value' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try a variation of a pivot query:

```
SELECT col1, col2 ,
   coalesce ( max( CASE WHEN m.COLA='XXX' THEN m.COLB END ), 'Not open' ) As XXX,
   coalesce ( max( CASE WHEN m.COLA='YYY' THEN m.COLB END ), 'Not open' ) As YYY,
   .....
   .....    
   coalesce ( max( CASE WHEN m.COLA='ZZZ' THEN m.COLB END ), 'Not open' ) As ZZZ 
FROM Test b
JOIN table_main c ON b.id=c.id
LEFT JOIN Table_A m ON m.id=b.id
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: It almost worked..except when `m.COLB` is NULL it should give me NULL but not 'Not open'. can u pls help here?

Comment: Just replace 'not open` string with `is null` in the appripriate rów in the select clause

Comment: Actually M.COLB will be some `varchar` most of the time and only sometimes it will be empty. So only when it is empty it should provide `null` instead of `not open`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite using `decode` and `LEFT JOIN` as follows.

```
  SELECT col1, col2 , 
  decode ( m.COLA , 'XXX' , m.COLB , 'Not Open' ) XXX ,
  decode ( m.COLA , 'YYY',  m.COLB , 'Not Open' ) YYY ,
  ...
  ...
  FROM Test b LEFT JOIN Table_A m ON m.id=b.id JOIN table_main c
  ON b.id=c.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is taking time because you are making several calls to a table to get your values. Simply reduce the number of calls being made to Table_A.

If the condition Table_A.id = m.id and m.COLA= 'Any Value' will always return one row then you can join the tables Table_A, Test and Table_main in a single join like below

```
Insert into my_table(col1, col2) values
select 
decode(a.COLA,'XXX' , a.COLB , 'Not Open'),
decode(a.COLA,'YYY' , a.COLB , 'Not Open'),
...
...
from Table_A a, Test b, Table_main c
where a.id = b.id
and b.id = c.id
```

In case the condition may return multiple records then you can use With clause like below

```
Insert into my_table(col1, col2) values
with table_a as (select col1, col2 , a.COLA, a.COLB
from Table_A a, Test b, Table_main c
where a.id = b.id
and b.id = c.id 
group by col1, col2,a.COLA, a.COLB)
select col1,col2,
decode(x.COLA,'XXX' , x.COLB , 'Not Open'),
decode(x.COLA,'YYY' , x.COLB , 'Not Open'),
....
....
from table_a x
```

Comment: While marking -ve to any answer , please provide the reason for the same. It will help  understanding what has been put wrong and should not be repeated.